# Splitting second column of a line to create multiple lines with a bash oneliner

Tags: awk, sed, cut, tr

I have a tab-separated data and it looks like this:

```
a   1a,2x,c1
b2  a4,4.6
3c  323
```

The second column has multiple comma seperated values.
I want to get this output:

```
a   1a
a   2x
a   c1
b2  a4
b2  4.6
3c  323
```

I was able to do it with this python code I wrote:

```
import sys
f = sys.argv[1]

with open(f) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
        genes = line[1].split(",")
        for gene in genes:
            print(line[0],gene, sep="\t")
```

I know I can do the same with a bash script but I would like to know how can I do this with a cool bash oneliner, using awk, sed, tr and/or cut without using a for loop.

I couldn't go any further than this:

`tr ',' '\n' data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's request without loop will be(tested and written with provided samples only),(Fair warning: `gsub` version with a pipe is curiosity from OP and it is both more fragile and slower than just using a for loop and keeping all processing inside of `awk`):

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,ORS $1 OFS)} 1'  Input_file | column -t
```

***Brief explanation:*** Using `gsub` function of `awk` to globally substitute all occurrences of `,` in each line with ORS(new line by default it value) $1(first field as per OP's requirement) OFS(space by default its value). Then mentioning `1` will print edited/non-edited line here. Then passing `awk` command's output to `column` command to beautify its output with same space.

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{num=split($2,array,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print $1,array[i]}}' Input_file
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code so I can understand it better?

Comment: That first script will fail silently and cryptically when `$1` contains `&`.

Comment: Second solution avoids regex and addresses presence of `&` or any other regex meta character in `$1`

Answer (score 4):

To avoid writing a loop, with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[,\n]' 'NF>1{k=$1} {print k, $NF}' file
a 1a
a 2x
a c1
b2 a4
b2 4.6
3c 323
```

By comparison a loop is clearer, simpler, and would work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]+|,' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' file
a 1a
a 2x
a c1
b2 a4
b2 4.6
3c 323
```

Performance wise there won't be a significant difference, they'll both run fast enough.

Comment: Now that is creative... And no `for` loop

Comment: Would using a for loop still be a better choice?

Comment: Yes because it's clearer, simpler, and would work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Comment: `awk -F '[[:blank:],]+' '...'` eliminates alternation.

Comment: @anubhava yes but then it'd fail if there were any empty fields since `,,` or `, ,` would be treated as a single FS. idk if there can be empty fields or not in this case of course but I'm just playing it safe.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F$'\t' '{split($2,arr,","); for(e in arr) print($1, arr[e])}' file
a 1a
a 2x
a c1
b2 a4
b2 4.6
3c 323
```

If you want the tab between col 1 and 2:

```
awk -F$'\t' '{split($2,arr,","); for(e in arr) print($1 "\t" arr[e])}'
a   1a
a   2x
a   c1
b2  a4
b2  4.6
3c  323
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using a for loop?

Comment: *Is it possible to do this without using a for loop?* Yes, but why? Your Python script has a `for` loop. Why make the `awk` script either slower or more fragile?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'[\t,]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $i }' file
a       1a
a       2x
a       c1
b2      a4
b2      4.6
3c      323
```

Use tab and comma as field separators and loop through the fields starting at the second field. Print the first field and the looped field value separated by a tab.

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed

```
sed -E ':a; s/([^ ]+) *([^,]+),([^,]+)/\1 \2\n\1 \3/; ta' infile
```

#### Explanation

This works by repeatedly matching 3 groups with the parenthesis.

- `([^ ]+)` match up-to first space
- `([^,]+)` match up-to the first comma
- `([^,]+)` match up-to a possible second comma
- `\1 \2\n\1 \3` substitute what was matched by the first group followed by the second group, then a new-line followed by the first group and third group

### Portable sed

*parse.sed*

```
:a
s/([^ ]+) *([^,]+),([^,]+)/\1 \2\
\1 \3/
ta
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -Ef parse.sed infile
```

Output in both case:

```
a 1a
a 2x
a c1
b2 a4
b2 4.6
3c  323
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code so I can understand it better? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^((.*\t)[^,]+),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace the first two tab separated values followed by a comma by the first two tab separated values, a newline and the first value followed by a tab. Print and delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.